# Flex/Actionscript - Traceing the contents of a variable of type Function

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, actionscript

for eg :

```
var func:Fuction = function ():void {
var i:int = 0;
return i;
};
```

Is there a way by which I can print the contents of the
variable func at run time?

By contents I mean the function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as actionscript code get's compiled and at runtime there is, more or less, no ,,human readable'' code left.